# Garbled UI with vnc, chicken-of-the-vnc, gridengine, qmon

Tags: xorg, ssh, vnc

Ubuntu 11.04

gridengine version 6.2u5-1ubuntu1

I start a desktop with the vncserver command.

My ~/.vnc/xstartup ends with 'gnome-session'.

I connect to it using chicken-of-the-VNC on my MacOSX Lion system.

I run 'qmon'. Much of qmon works, but several critical tasks show hopelessly garbled grid layouts. I have filed a bug report, but I suspect that there is something I am missing that would render (ahem) them legible.

Answer (score 2):

I would try a different VNC client / server combination or at least look into the server settings:

[This is a good beginning](http://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011/08/03/setting-up-the-vnc-server-in-mac-os-x-10-7-aka-lion/)

[image]

FreeNX

---

Another possible option would be FreeNX / NX server. This option is fast, secure, and available cross platform.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX and http://www.nomachine.com/select-package-client.php

As of yet there is not a server for OSX, but there is a client.